# Hyperledger Fabric - Ledger encryption

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have some doubts related to data registered in the ledger in HL Fabric v1.4.0.

1. Are the data stored in the peers encrypted (world state and blockchain)?
2. In which files of the peer is stored the ledger (blockchain part)?
3. Is it possible to read data from the ledger data without using a chaincode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Data is not encrypted by default. The [FAQ](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/Fabric-FAQ.html?highlight=encryption) recommends using file system encryption on the peer to achieve this. If you're using private data collections or channels the data may be encrypted even without this.
2. The ledger is stored in a LevelDB database. The data can be found in 
   `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData` 
   (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649527/in-hyperledger-fabric-blocks-locations-and-validity-criteria)). A separate CouchDB database [can also be used](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_tutorial.html), in that case you can configure the storage location to your liking.
3. You can use the [Hyperledger Fabric REST API SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest) to query ledger data. Hyperledger Composer also provides a REST API for your business application. You could probably read the files directly as well, since they're basically LevelDB/CouchDB database files, although I've never tried that.